# Can't send email with video/audio attachment on iphone!

Tags: iphone, video, email, attachment, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to send an email with MFMailComposeViewController. I'm able to send emails with images attached, but when I try to attach mp3 or mp4 files I get this message:

DA|Could not open the lock file at /tmp/DAAccountsLoading.lock. We'll load the accounts anyway, but bad things may happen

(if seems to appear right after I start filling the "To" field), and sending the message fails.

Here is my code (The HelperUtils class is just something I created and I'm sure the problem is not there):

```
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[HelperUtils getPathWithEnding:media.name]];
NSString *mimeTypeStr = [HelperUtils getMimeTypeOfFileWithPath:[HelperUtils getPathWithEnding:media.name]];
NSLog(mimeTypeStr);
NSLog([HelperUtils getPathWithEnding:media.name]);
[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:mimeTypeStr fileName:media.name];
```

Comment: After looking at it again, sending mp3 files works, but it fails with mp4. Did anyone manage to attach video files?

Comment: how big are your video files?  there's a 15MB limit.  I think the message about locking is unrelated.

Comment: actually they are like 7MB. Another thing that I noticed is that when I send an mp3 file (which is like 5 MB) it all goes well, but the second (or third if I'm lucky) the application crashes.

Comment: Apple's MFMailComposer itself actually contains some pretty bad memory leaks that have not been addressed. http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development-advanced-discussion/23645-sending-email-using-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-not-releasing-memory.html https://devforums.apple.com/message/121093#121093

Comment: I think this message is unrelated. I get it all the time.  If you check the timing, you'll probably get this message when you select an email address from the contacts book, before you press 'Send' (and in your case, it crashes)

Answer (score 5):

```
NSString *mp3File = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"tmp.mp3"];
NSURL    *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:mp3File];
NSData *soundFile = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
[mailDialogController addAttachmentData:soundFile mimeType:@"audio/mpeg" fileName:@"tmp.mp3"];
```

works for me with mp3 files. when you say it fails with mp4, in what way?

if app is crashing after a few, you have a memory leak somewhere most likely.

Comment: How about video.... my video is just 66769 bytes. I still not able to attach the video to mail