# Attach ipod library audio file to Email in iphone app

Tags: iphone, email, mpmediapickercontroller

I am working on app where i am attaching a Audio file from ipod library 
i Get the audio  detail using MPMediaPickerController. I get all the details. I even get the  path and URl for the Audio. I even attach the audio in email and which is visible in compose view of the Email.
But when it is sent it is not visible.
Plz help me with the same.

```
 -(void)displayComposerSheet {
NSMutableString *sub=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
[sub setString:[NSString stringWithString:@"HiFive"]];
    NSURL *assetURL = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

NSString *str=[song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
str=[str stringByAppendingFormat:@".mp3"];
AVURLAsset *songAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:assetURL options:nil];

NSError *assetError = nil;
AVAssetReader *assetReader = [[AVAssetReader assetReaderWithAsset:songAsset
                                                            error:&assetError]retain];
if (assetError) {
    NSLog (@"error: %@", assetError);
    return;
}

AVAssetReaderOutput *assetReaderOutput = [[AVAssetReaderAudioMixOutput 
                                           assetReaderAudioMixOutputWithAudioTracks:songAsset.tracks
                                           audioSettings: nil]
                                          retain];
if (! [assetReader canAddOutput: assetReaderOutput]) {
    NSLog (@"can't add reader output... die!");
    return;
}
[assetReader addOutput: assetReaderOutput];

NSArray *dirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [dirs objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *exportPath = [[documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:str] retain];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:exportPath]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:exportPath error:nil];
}
NSString *Newpath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectoryPath,str];
NSURL *exportURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportPath];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:exportPath toPath:Newpath error:nil];
NSURL *theFileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:Newpath];
NSLog(@"theFileUrl: %@",theFileUrl);
NSLog(@"Newpath: %@",Newpath);

NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:Newpath];
NSLog(@"%d",[data length]);
NSString *eMailBody=[NSString stringWithString:@"I am with you!!!"];
NSString *encodedBody =[eMailBody stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


MFMailComposeViewController *controller = 
[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[controller addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"audio/mp3" fileName:str];
[controller setSubject:sub];
[controller setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",encodedBody] isHTML:NO];
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];


/*
// Converts the sound's file path to an NSURL object
NSURL *newURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];
NSData *data=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:newURL];
NSString *eMailBody=[NSString stringWithString:@"I am with you!!!"];
NSString *encodedBody =[eMailBody stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

MFMailComposeViewController *controller = 
[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[controller addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"audio/x-caf" fileName:@"sound"];
[controller setSubject:sub];
[controller setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",encodedBody] isHTML:NO];
//[controller setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"abhishek@iarianatech.com"]]; 
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
 */
```

}

the image after atachment looks like this [image]

the image after atachment looks like this ![email gets sent but we dont get the attachment in actual mail

Comment: user attachment type - audio/mpeg instead audio/mp3. see here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/1921691/140765

Comment: stil not working Sir...?

Comment: do i need to copy audio in application and pass on the new path and URL to attachment.