# iPhone SDK email video

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t send email with video/audio attachment on iphone!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921691/cant-send-email-with-video-audio-attachment-on-iphone)

so for the past couple of days I have been trying to email a video. I got it to successfully select the video, but I can't figure out how to put it in an email. Thanks.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NULL];
    NSURL *mediaUrl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailcomposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    mailcomposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;





    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){

        [mailcomposer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"random@random.com", nil]];
        [mailcomposer setSubject:@""];
        [mailcomposer setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
        [mailcomposer addAttachmentData:mediaUrl mimeType:@"video/mp4" fileName:@"Video"];
        [self presentViewController:mailcomposer animated:YES completion:NULL];

    }


}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are adding the URL as an attachment, you need to attach NSData by converting that URL to data like so

```
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:mediaUrl];
```

and then

```
[mailcomposer addAttachmentData:videoData mimeType:@"video/mp4" fileName:@"Video"];
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Upvoted comment and answer since answer was never selected as "The Answer". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
[mailcomposer addAttachmentData:mediaUrl mimeType:@"video/mp4" fileName:@"Video"];
```

Seriously? Haven't you read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008200-CH1-SW2) of `MFMailComposerViewController`? `addAttachmentData:` expects an `NSData` and **not** an URL. You have to read the file into memory (using NSData) and add that data to the mail composer controller.

But you should probably not do this anyways. Large video files consume a lot of memory.